# Full text search returning only one row and not a set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

I have a full text search catalog and index set up on my table.
I first tried to run the query below with only one row in the table and it worked by returning the row I was looking based on the string 'test'. But when I placed a second row into the table it still only returned one row, not two rows. I'm trying to get it to return more then one row and I'm not sure why it's not. Any help would be appreciated.

Query's attempted

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Gifts
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, 'test')

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Gifts
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"test gift"')

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Gifts
WHERE FREETEXT (Name, 'test gift')

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Gifts
WHERE FREETEXT(Name, 'test')
```

and here are the two rows in the table

```
╔════════╦════════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ GiftId ║    Name    ║ Rating ║ Status ║ OwnerId ║ Availability ║ Thumbnail ║
╠════════╬════════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║     1  ║ test gift  ║      5 ║      0 ║       1 ║            0 ║ NULL      ║
║     2  ║ test gift1 ║      2 ║      0 ║       1 ║            0 ║ NULL      ║
╚════════╩════════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Only the first row is being returned with giftid = 1 and I want both rows to be returned.

Comment: Shouldn't there be more then one returned result? It seems like it but I could be wrong based on the way freetext and contains work. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: After you added that 2nd row, did you repopulate the full text index? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx).